# pass by value vs non-const reference vs const reference in comparison function

Tags: c++, arguments, comparator

```
/**
 * Definition for an interval.
 * struct Interval {
 *     int start;
 *     int end;
 *     Interval() : start(0), end(0) {}
 *     Interval(int s, int e) : start(s), end(e) {}
 * };
 */
class SummaryRanges {
public:
    SummaryRanges() {

    }

    void addNum(int val) {
        auto it = st.lower_bound(Interval(val, val));
        int start = val, end = val;
        if(it != st.begin() && (--it)->end+1 < val) it++;
        while(it != st.end() && val+1 >= it->start && val-1 <= it->end)
        {
            start = min(start, it->start);
            end = max(end, it->end);
            it = st.erase(it);
        }
        st.insert(it,Interval(start, end));
    }
private:
    struct Cmp{
        bool operator()(const Interval& a, const Interval& b) { return a.start < b.start;} //works
//      bool operator()(Interval& a, Interval& b) { return a.start < b.start;} //error
//      bool operator()(Interval a, Interval b) { return a.start < b.start;} //works
    };
    set<Interval, Cmp> st;
};
```

I want objects of custom class `Interval` to be sorted in `std::set`. The arguments in `operator()()` can be either value or `const` reference. But it would report following error when passing non-`const` reference to the arguments.

```
required from ‘std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::lower_bound(const key_type&) [with _Key = Interval; _Val = Interval; _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<Interval>; _Compare = SummaryRanges::Cmp; _Alloc = std::allocator<Interval>; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<Interval>; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = Interval]’
```

Why does passing non-`const` reference in `std::set` fail?

Comment: "But it would report error  " - which you should include in your question post, as the content probably describes (though somewhat cryptically for a beginner) what is *actually* wrong. `std::set` sends const-references to your comparator, which won't work if the comparator requires non-const references. You can send mutable references to a function requesting immutable references; the reverse is *not* the case.

Comment: I added the error report, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`std::set` values are immutable and are essentually `const`. In addition, all member function taking l-value references take `const` reference. `const` values cannot bind to the non-`const` references and you cannot pass constant reference parameter to the non-const comparison function argument.